# Embed an external widget, but it comes back as undefined before proper script can load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using Create React App and trying to embed an external widget, but am having trouble with implementation.

My app always gives me the below error

Failed to compile:
WidgetUIName is not defined

The widget that I am trying to embed relies on the script that i'm attaching to the head which takes a second to load. If I set up code to wait until a condition is met to execute a function that initializes the widget, react app still fails to compile.

```
 // My App.js File
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyAppContainer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


//MyAppContainer
function MyAppContainer() {
  return (
    <div id="ui-widget">
      {/* setting a condition here like waiting for my page to load before calling this component still fails to compile */}
      <MyWidgetContainer /> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyAppContainer;



// My Widget Container
function MyWidgetContainer() {

useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = "https://widgetJS/widgetJSUI.min.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.head.appendChild(script);

    script.onload = () => {
        let widget = new WidgetUIName({
               containerId: "ui-widget",
               //widget props set here
    )}

    return () => {
        document.head.removeChild(script);
    }
}, []);

  return (
     <div>my widget</div>
  );

   }

 export default MyWidgetContainer;
```

Adding the below line before i write 'let widget =' removes the error, but the widget won't initialize with this.

```
  let GMPaymentUI = function () { }
```

I can initialize the widget no problem if I use the app's index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://widgetJS/widgetJSUI.min.js"></script>
   <title>My App</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="root"></div>
   <div id="ui-widget"></div>
   <script>
     let widget = new WidgetUIName({
                containerId: "ui-widget",
                //widget props set here
     });
   </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: 1) Add the script to the index file 2) add `/* global WidgetUIName */` (yes, as comment) to the React class that is using it

Comment: Can you download the script (or install it as a package using npm or yarn) and then include it in your component? That completely eliminates this type of issue.

Comment: Wow that comment /* global WidgetUIName */ totally worked! Thanks Chris G! Downloading the script is also a good idea, thanks tmdesigned!